# ionic 2 DatePicker

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I'm new to ionic and I'm playing with ionic 2 beta. I'm trying to implement a native datepicker using cordova plugin like [in the documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/DatePicker/).

I've fully copy/paste the example, and I get `"ReferenceError: DatePicker is not defined` on Nexus 5 Emulator and Archos android phone.

```
openDatePicker() {
    var options = {
      date: new Date(),
      mode: 'date'
    };

    function onSuccess(date) {
        alert('Selected date: ' + date);
    }

    function onError(error) { // Android only
        alert('Error: ' + error);
    }

    DatePicker.show(options, onSuccess, onError);
  }
```

I've searched a lot and found nothing about this, maybe I'm doing it wrong with cordova plugin on Ionic 2?

Comment: Hi @ MoKAt can you please provide html part of code to know the exact solution, now I'M trying to do ionic 2 date picker, i have tried many ways it's not useful to me , so can you please help for that?....thanks...

Comment: I don't think I still have that code, but the answer (and the documentation) is giving all needed informations since I've made it work with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation on this is lacking (the Ionic Native docs at the time of this question are still very much a WIP).

`ionic-native` is a separate module from the framework, so you'll need to install it:

```
# from within your project directory
npm install --save ionic-native
```

You'll also need to install the plugin you're trying to use if you haven't already:

```
#from within your project directory
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-datepicker
```

Then import the `DatePicker` plugin in your code:

```
import {DatePicker} from 'ionic-native';
```

And then same as Ionic 1 you won't be able to use any plugins until Cordova is ready.  This means you can either use [Platform.ready](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/Platform/#ready) or wait for the `deviceready` event to fire on `window`:

```
constructor(platform: Platform) {
  platform.ready().then(() => {
    let options = {
      date: new Date(),
      mode: 'date'
    }

    DatePicker.show(options).then(
      date => {
        alert('Selected date: ' + date);
      },
      error => {
        alert('Error: ' + error);
      }
    );
  });
}
```

Also one thing to note is that `ionic-native` wraps the callbacks in a promise.

Comment: Thanks for this good answer, but I'm still having trouble, I've installed ionic-native (and rxjs because of dependancies), I've got the folder in node_modules, and it's referenced in package.json, but  build is failing `Cannot resolve module 'ionic-native'`

Comment: The last release was bad, try updating now: `npm install ionic-native`

Comment: It works ! Thanks a lot ! Fast update I'm impressed :)

Comment: Hi I have tried your method and it works. However I would like to display a calender and let the user select the date from it. May I know if you have any suggestions?
I used ionic-datepicker (https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-datepicker) previously for ionic 1 but there are some problems when using in ionic 2.
I installed it using `npm install https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-datepicker` and called with `import {ionic-datepicker} from 'ionic-datepicker';`
Its giving me a syntax error with the - in ionic-datepicker

Comment: @Tim maybe you could have a look to that question related to the same topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40791000/ionic-2-date-picker-cordova-plugin-property-android-themes-does-not-exist

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
step 1: npm install @ionic-native/core --save
step 2: npm install --save @ionic-native/date-picker
step 3: add this plugin to your app.module.ts
          i. import { DatePicker } from '@ionic-native/date-picker';
         ii. providers:[DatePicker]
step 4: import { DatePicker } from '@ionic-native/date-picker';
step 5: Inject in constructor:
        constructor(public datePicker: DatePicker) { }
step 6: You can access datePicker like: 
        this.datePicker.show({
         date: new Date(),
             mode: 'date',
             androidTheme: this.datePicker.ANDROID_THEMES.THEME_HOLO_DARK
         }).then(
             date => console.log('Date: ', date),
             err => console.log('Error while getting date: ', err)
         );
```