# Ionic 2, Date Picker (cordova plugin). Property 'ANDROID_THEMES' does not exist on type 'typeof DatePicker'

Tags: ionic2, cordova-plugins

I have installed the [plugin Date Picker](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/date-picker/) in my project.

In a component wich has `import { DataPicker } from 'ionic-native'` on top, if I use it like that **(with androidTheme parameter commented) it WORKS**:

```
  let options = {
      date: new Date(),
      mode: 'date',
      // androidTheme: DatePicker.ANDROID_THEMES.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT
  };

    DatePicker.show(options).then(
      (date) => {
      console.log('date_value:' + date)
  }).catch( (error) => { });
```

If I uncomment `androidTheme:DatePicker.ANDROID_THEMES.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT`, It will bug during the building process throwing:

> Property 'ANDROID_THEMES' does not exist on type 'typeof DatePicker'

I did a `npm install ionic-native` in CLI in my project folder as [advised here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35815279/ionic-2-datepicker) but it did not fix the problem. It gives me the following output (that seems ok to me):

> `-- ionic-native@2.0.3
>
> npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
>
> npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.15

When I look under `[my project]\plugins\cordova-plugin-datepicker\www`, it contains 3 folders corresponding to the 3 platforms (ios, android, windows) with each a JS file named 'DatePicker.js' and in the one below the android folder it contains in the code:

```
/**
 * Android themes
 */
DatePicker.prototype.ANDROID_THEMES = {
  THEME_TRADITIONAL          : 1, // default
  THEME_HOLO_DARK            : 2,
  THEME_HOLO_LIGHT           : 3,
  THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK  : 4,
  THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT : 5
};
```

If I look in `[my project]\nodes_modules\ionic-native\dist\plugins\` , the file `datepicker.js` exists (of course) but does not contain the particularities of each platform.

What's wrong? Why `datepicker.js` under `[my project]\nodes_modules\ionic-native\dist\plugins\` does not contain the particularity of each platform despite the plugin was added to the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a work around for it:

in [my project]\nodes_modules\ionic-native\dist\plugins[android|ios|windows]\datepicker.js

At the end of the code it is written:

```
var datePicker = new DatePicker();
module.exports = datePicker;

// Make plugin work under window.plugins
if (!window.plugins) {
    window.plugins = {};
}
if (!window.plugins.datePicker) {
    window.plugins.datePicker = datePicker;
}
```

Hence, it makes datePicker (starting with lower case) different from DatePicker (starting with upper case from ionic-native).

In the component where I required it, I've just declare before the component:

```
declare var datePicker: any;
```

Then inside that component I've changed my code with:

```
 let options = {
      date: new Date(),
      mode: 'date',
      androidTheme: datePicker.ANDROID_THEMES.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT
  };

    DatePicker.show(options).then(
      (date) => {
      console.log('date_value:' + date)
  }).catch( (error) => { });
```

It works.

Comment: Hi @nyluje  can you please provide html part of code to know the exact solution, now I'M trying to do ionic 2 date picker, i have tried many ways it's not useful to me , so can you please help for that?..then if you update the plunker is very easier to understand and useful to us..thanks... –

Comment: Look at the answer to that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40751535/ionic-2-add-custom-input-component-in-a-form-within-a-page-final-goal-integr/40791281#40791281 I had posted the full code I used.